# AppointmentItem.GetInspector returns null in if Outlook Application is closed

Tags: c#, html, outlook, rtf, appointment

I am creating a desktop application using c# to create and send outlook appointment. I am trying to convert html text to rtf text using word editor. Following is the line from my code to get the word editor object -

```
inspector = OLAppointmentItem.GetInspector;
Word.Document sDoc = inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
```

When MS Outlook application is in open state then i am able to get the inspector object and using the word editor of that inspector object, I open a html file and save it as rtf file. Later I open this rtf file and assigns the RTF text to RTFBody property of OlAppointmentItem.

But When MS Outlook is closed then  OLAppointmentItem.GetInspector returns null and I failed to convert HTML text to RTF text. Please advise if there is any alternate way to send HTML text in Appointment body.

My final objective is to send HTML template in Appointment body.

Answer (score 0):

An Inspector represents an open Outlook windows, so if Outlook is closed and you start Outlook via code then you have to actively display an item (e.g. AppointmentItem.Display) in order to open a window for it and access its Inspector.

But if you just need to access the HTML, use AppointmentItem.HTMLBody.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I didn't find AppointmentItem.HTMLBody property. I tried to use Redemption appointment as well but got stuck in different issues like RDOAppointmentItem.HTMLBody is not able to carry tables from HTML template. To overcome this issue, i work on this idea that convert html template to rtf first and then use it in rtf body property.

Comment: My bad, there is no HTMLBody on the AppointmentItem object. But it is available via RDOMail.HTMLBody; you can cast an RDOMail object from an RDOAppointmentItem object. I'm not sure what you mean about carrying "tables from an HTML template" - can you clarify?

Comment: Carrying tables from HTML template I mean that I have a HTML file having some text in tabular format. If I read this file and assign the html text to RDOAppointment.HTMLBody property then the text which is in tabular format disappears at recipients side if recipient is using Android or iOS device. While on Windows it works fine. You talked about casting of objects. Is it possible to create RDOMailItem and assign html text to it then cast this mail to appointment?